# How to handle acronyms in class names?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, class-names

Instead of explaning I'll provide a simple and short example:

I would call a class that parses XMLs `XMLParser`. Sometime I run into problems, 
e.g. I want to create a class that labels XMLs, but `XMLLabeler` seems kind of odd, because of the two same letters.

Since XML is a wide spread term it should be no problem to resolve this 'issue',
but for more complex acronyms this leaves a bad taste.

How would you handle these kind of things? Stricty applying camel case? I. e. `XmlParser`, `XmlLabeler`? Are there any naming conventions for acronyms in class names?

Comment: As per JLS 6.2 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2 I'm apparently referring to identifiers and not names...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Camel Case (XmlParser) is the preferred way because it is easier to read

Comment: Could you back that up please?

Comment: Effective Java (1st ed) p.165- 166: "While  uppercase is more common, a strong argument can be made in favor of capitalizing only the first letter.  Even if multiple acronyms occur back-to-back, you can still tell where one word starts and the next word ends.  Which class name would you rather see, HTTPURL or HttpUrl ?"